# How to handle deploying w/ Git in an environment where the integration branch isn't always ready for live

Tags: git, deployment, branch

So I realize that's a doozy of a title, so let me be clarify. I have an environment with 15 developers, and at any given point, up to 5 of us might be working on the same set of code. This is a PHP web app that's got a lot of legacy/procedural code, so we're often editing the same files, and some of our changes can be quite far-reaching.

As a result, integration is somewhat tricky, but even more to the point, sometimes a feature will be developed that goes through multiple rounds of QA & review by marketing, all while other, smaller features need to be deployed.

Currently, to avoid things getting stuck at QA/integration, the `integration` branch is a sort-of dead-end branch, and when something is truly ready, it's merged directly from its feature branch into `master`, and `master` is pushed to deploy to the live site.

I'm trying to create a smoother workflow, where features merge into QA, and then QA merges into `master` as a deployment, but I need to address the issue of features that aren't ready to go live being intermingled with smaller features on `integration`. I'm willing to explore some alternate way(s) to handle the longer-running features, rather than them merging into the `integration` branch, but I've hit the wall myself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adopt the idea of a "Release Candidate".

I've explained the process for doing so here: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

Let me know if you have any questions about this work-flow.

Comment: Whew, that's some serious mojo you've got going on. Thanks for the great write-up, but I'll definitely need to marinate on that a little bit before I can even formulate questions. Stay tuned :)

Comment: One big stumbling block is that our code is **so** far away from following the Open/Close Principle. Tons of legacy, procedural code, hacked together with metaphorical baling wire and duct tape. I based my initial thoughts on a branching model from the same article you referenced, however (the "Successful Branching Model" post).

Comment: This is an ideal situation. It works equally well in legacy. It forces better practices within it.

Comment: Ok, here's a question: the "Share Your Hard Work" section, with regards to sharing the results of `rerere`, you say "Currently this is a branch that has it’s own independent root", but don't go into any detail on how, exactly you accomplish this. Would you please detail that?

Answer (score 0):

The fact of the matter is that, with N features, you have N+(N choose 2)+(N choose 3)+(N choose 4)+...+1 different combinations.

In English, that's "oh God there are a lot of combinations".

So, you don't create integration branches for every possible subset of your features: you only test the combinations that you *care* about. If something isn't ready for prime time by itself, there's no way it's ready for prime time in tandem with other features. Once **all** the features going into a *particular* release are mature, you create an integration branch with all of them together, QA that, and then ship it.

You may do "advance integration" testing just to see how well 2, 3, 4 or so features play with each other, but those branches aren't "authoritative" with respect to QA: because you don't have the final set of everything that's going to be shipped in there, you can't call anything you do true QA.

So you don't have **an** "integration" branch - each integration branch is for one *complete* batch of things which are ready for QA. If anything makes its way in there that's not good, the whole branch is going to fail QA, so nothing will creep its way from the bad branch into the deployed state - that means you never have to say "this bit is good, that bit is bad, pull that, leave this" *after* the QA process: that would be creating an essentially untested combination of features.

Comment: Thanks for the objective view @Borealid, it's gotten a bit "forest v. trees" for me lately with this. It's tricky to separate things into releases around here, due to the nature of our "features" (they tend to be tests of various sales funnels, though there's lots of other things too).